# Variety Affine Space

Tags: polynomials, affine-geometry

I have the following question which i'm not sure how to work out...

$For\ f=6x^2y-xy^2-2y^3+1\ and\ \ h=3x-2y\ \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Show that V(f,h) is empty.

What can you say about the ideal (f,h)?

I'm really not sure how I go about answering these questions.. any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint:

Note that f can be written as f=1+(3x-2y)(2x+y)y

Comment: Im just not sure how you actually go about showing whether a variety is empty or not..